# How to verify server SSL certificate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, httpclient, httparty

I am a newbie on SSL concept, I am trying to connect to API which has x509 mutual auth using HTTParty.

I got client cert, client key and server cert (all are pem files).

I got it working with client cert and key and with `verify: false`.

Now next step is how to verify server cert also?

HTTParty documentation link https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/tree/master/docs#working-with-ssl

```
class ServiceClient
  include HTTParty
  DEFAULT_HEADERS = {
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
  }.freeze
  base_uri 'https://example.com'
  pem File.read("#{File.expand_path('.')}/path/to/certs/cert.pem")

  def self.iframe_url(**payload)
    post(
     '/test/create',
     body: payload.to_json,
     headers: DEFAULT_HEADERS,
     verify: false
    )
  end
end
```

Call to service client

```
payload = {user_id: "100", account_id: "1234"} 
ServiceClient.iframe_url(payload)
```

**Edit:**

HTTParty is not a hard requirement so solution with any http client would work for me.

If I remove `verify: false` I get below error.

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed
```

Comment: This code is missing a *lot* of context and the relationship of the constants, variables, and method calls to that `iframe_url` method are far from clear.

Comment: Added more details. I was just looking for pointers on how to specify server cert and validate response against it. HTTParty Documentation doesn't have any details on this. I guess answer might be pretty simple but I am unable to find any reference on how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: You could clean that up a bit as `File.read(File.expand_path('./path/to/certs/cert.pem`))` instead. No need to interpolate strings.

Comment: Does HTTParty let you get the server certificate for verification purposes? I know it's a pretty good library for "quick and easy" integrations, but I'm not sure it's all that sophisticated.

Comment: I think it does but not confident. Code shows that cert_store param can be sent thru options.

Comment: `verify: false` does not verify the server as you can see in the source code https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/lib/httparty/connection_adapter.rb:160. By default `verify` and `verify_peer` are set to `true`

Comment: @KartikeyTanna yes, I understand that. I have set verify false just to check my request is going thru. When I remove it, request fails and that is where I need to implement server cert validation.

Comment: Can you dump the error message?

Comment: updated error message in question itself

Answer (score 4):

By default, the TLS protocol only proves the identity of the server to the
client, leaving the authentication of the client to the server to the
application layer, e.g., HTTP Basic authentication.

Mutual TLS authentication refers to the client and server authenticating each
other at the same time. It can be used as an alternative to HTTP Basic
authentication. It's also often called certificate-based authentication.

Looks like you're getting this error (but works with `verify: false`) because
the server certificate isn't trusted. Is it self-signed? Or perhaps the
certificate authority (CA) who issued the certificate isn't trusted in your system.

HTTParty is built on top of `Net::HTTP`, which uses `OpenSSL`, which gets the
trusted CA certificates from the system, e.g. `/etc/ssl/cert.pem`. Although you
could override the `SSL_CERT_FILE` environment variable, I don't think it's a
good idea because it might impact other parts of your application. A better
solution would be to pass the CA certificates to HTTParty only.

I've never used HTTParty, so bear with me. But taking a quick look at the
[code](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/lib/httparty/connection_adapter.rb#L181)
and assuming you're using the default `ConnectionAdapter`, looks like you need
to define both `pem` and `ssl_ca_file` options, which will define the client
and CA certificate files, respectively. Also note that by doing it so, [it will
turn certificate verification
on](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/lib/httparty/connection_adapter.rb#L198).

```
class ServiceClient
  include HTTParty
  pem "path/to/client_cert_and_key.pem"
  ssl_ca_file "path/to/ca_certificates.pem"
end
```

I don't think it's related to your issue, but if your client key has a
passphrase, make sure to pass it on `pem(pem_contents, password)`.

HTH. Best.

Answer (score 1):

Try as you I suppose you are using ssl certificate that you want to verify. Also it's quite easier in RestClient, I am adding snippet at the end.

```
class ServiceClient
  include HTTParty
  DEFAULT_HEADERS = {
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
  }.freeze
  base_uri 'https://example.com'
  ssl_ca_file "#{File.expand_path('.')}/path/to/certs/cert.pem"


  def self.iframe_url(**payload)
    post(
     '/test/create',
     body: payload.to_json,
     headers: DEFAULT_HEADERS,
    )
  end
end
```

Rest Client solution:

```
client = RestClient::Resource.new('https://example.com/',
                              :ssl_client_cert => p12.certificate,
                              :ssl_client_key => p12.key,
                              :verify_ssl => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)
```

Comment: `OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE` doesn't verify SSL, right? The question is about how to verify it.

Answer (score 1):

This should solve the problem:

```
RestClient::Resource.new(
  'https://example.com',
  :ssl_client_cert  =>  OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read("cert.pem")),
  :ssl_client_key   =>  OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read("key.pem"), "passphrase, if any"),
  :ssl_ca_file      =>  "ca_certificate.pem",
  :verify_ssl       =>  OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
).get
```

Ref: https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client

Answer (score -1):

Use " OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE"

In your code , maybe look like to：

```
    class ServiceClient
      include HTTParty
      OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
      {...your code...}
    end
```

Comment: This defeats the purpose as it is bypassing the server cert validation.

Comment: Are you redefining the constant `VERIFY_PEER`? Major WTF!!